# Adding chevron to list view item

Tags: listview, react-native

My Component's render() method is like that:

```
if (this.props.loading) {
  return this.renderLoadingView();
}

return (
  <View style={[GlobalStyles.mainContainer, CategoryListingStyles.container]}>
    <ListView
      style={GlobalStyles.listView}
      dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
      enableEmptySections={true}
      renderRow={(c) => <CategoryListingItem category={c} onSelectCategory={this.selectCategory} />}
      renderSeparator={(sectionID, rowID) => <View key={`${sectionID}-${rowID}`} style={CategoryListingStyles.separator} />}
    />
  </View>
);
```

It displays a simple list but **I would like to add a chevron to the right** to make it more clear to the user that taping on it would take the user to the next screen.

What's the best approach for that? Image? If yes, how can I append it, where? I can't use any pseudo selectors in CSS, as far as I know.

Comment: also tried changing the view with no effect: `<Text key={\`${sectionID}-${rowID}\`} style={CategoryListingStyles.separator}>test</Text>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) includes a chevron icon, as well as many other icons.

Installation:

```
npm install react-native-vector-icons --save
rnpm link
```

The `angle-right` icon from the Font Awesome collection makes a good iOS style chevron:

Import:

```
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome';
```

In render method:

```
<Icon name="angle-right" size={24} color="#C8C7CC" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a paginated scroll it would be better to try out ViewPagerAndroid in case of Android. You can also have a look at the component react-native-swiper https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper

Also to answer your question, my initial thought is to add an Image in a TouchabeView with absolute positioning and then to rig the onPress to the ListView.scrollTo(). Not sure if this the best way though. Something along the lines of

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={scrollFunction} style={{position:'absolute',right:0}}>
  <Image source={chevronIcon} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```